# getting `GLIBC_2.18' not found error in aws api gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, chalice, web3py

I am writing an Api in aws chalice.
My code is working good in local.

But I am getting the following respnse:
`{ "message": "Internal server error" }` 
My requirements.txt file contains:

```
web3==5.12.1
pycryptodome==3.9.8
```

On checking in aws api gateway. Found the following error:

Error Message:

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /var/task/rusty_rlp.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"}
Fri Sep 18 13:47:33 UTC 2020 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Unable to import module 'app': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /var/task/rusty_rlp.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so). Lambda request id: b8a849f9-2982-49a6-a010-f6a2dbe1655e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing mu requirements file solved it  :

```
eth-account==0.5.2
rlp==1.2.0
web3==5.10.0
```